# C++ GUI Toolkit with OpenGL Support

Tags: c++, opengl, cross-platform, gui-toolkit

I've been looking for a good C/C++ GUI Toolkit for some time now, and have found these to be the general requirements:

I need it to be:
    Good looking
    cross-platform
    C++ or C that will compile w/C++, either is fine
    OpenGL support
    can be used in commercial applications without royalties (no licensing snags)

What I've used in the past and why they aren't what I need:
-Win32 (not cross-platform)
-FLTK (grey, flat, and visually unappealing, but otherwise excellent)

I've been looking at GTK rather closely, the only problem being that it doesn't have reliable OpenGL support as far as I can tell (some 3rd party support only?)
Qt's license does not allow commercial development without a licensing fee.

By OpenGL support, I mean OpenGL views in the toolkit (embeddable).

Comment: Can you elaborate on "OpenGL support"? Does it need to embed OpenGL views (like GTK can) or be entirely rendered in OpenGL itself?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/good-gui-for-opengl could help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to reconsider [Qt](http://qtsoftware.com) as your answer, and you are a few years behind on the license changes since Nokia acquired them -- that is no longer a concern as it is LGPL these days.  And support for OpenGL is just one of many strong points in favor.

Comment: You only need to buy a commercial license if you are going to use the commercial version of Qt. Using the LGPL version has no cost and also let's you to develop any commercial application as long as you use dinamic linking, i.e. not including the Qt code inside your own application but keeping it independent.

Answer (score 3):

The three major ones, GTK+, wxWidgets, and Qt, all use a form of the LGPL.  Unless you are unable to dynamically link to the GUI libraries on your architecture, you can distribute all the commercial software you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you asked for, but another possibility is to use a standard openGL windows (for example using GLFW) and do the GUI yourself, for instance with ceGUI.

It's definetely possible to have the gui in one part of the screen, and a 3D view in another, just like you'll get with a toolkit.

(but personally I'd go with Qt though)

Answer (score 0):

we have a toolkit, XVT.  if you are looking for help in writing it, we can do that too.